# Nested loop when inner loop index unequal outer loop index

Tags: c, logic, nested-loops

Nested loop logic to skip the inner loop when its index equals the outer loop index.

Used an if statement within the inner loop to the effect of:

```
for (i=0;i<N;i++)
  for (j=0;j<N;j++)
    if (j!=i)
      ... some code
```

I believe this gives me the expected results but is there a less CPU consuming method that I may not be aware of?

Comment: You could use two inner loops to avoid `j != i` with: `for(j=0;j<i;j++) {...} for(j=i+1;j<N;j++) {...}` but is this particular check a bottleneck?

Comment: @WeatherVane: I only noticed your comment after posting my answer... I am not surprised we are once again in complete agreement.

Comment: @chqrlie should your second loop be `for (++j; ` etc ? Am unsure where the sequence point is.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I made the code more explicit about this `j++`.

Comment: Thank you both. A separate loop did indeed shave off a good 15% CPU time for the overall code.

Comment: @PeterC: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score and upvote it once you have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume that `N <= i`, you can split the inner loop into 2 separate `for` loops to reduce the number of tests:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        ... some code
    }
    /* here we have j == i, skip this one */
    j++;
    for (; j < N; j++) {
        ... same code
    }
}
```

This results in more code but half as many tests on `j`. Note however that if `N` is a constant, the compiler might unroll the original inner loop more efficiently. Careful benchmarking is the only way to determine if this solution is worth the effort for your problem, compiler and architecture.

For completeness, this code can be simplified as:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        ... some code
    }
    /* here we have j == i, skip this one */
    while (++j < N) {
        ... same code
    }
}
```